# Connecting to a "P2P Wifi camera"

Tags: ios, camera, vlc, wifip2p

I have a Chinese "P2P Wifi Camera" (model Q5) that i'd like to connect to from an iOS app.

The camera can operate in "LAN Mode" - in this mode i'm connecting from the phone/computer to the wifi network of the camera itself, and an app called "P2PCamViewer" displays the current picture.

However, i wasn't able to connect to it using my own code.
As far as i can tell, the camera doesn't respond to HTTP or RTSP requests, on any port (probed it using nmap). i also wasn't able to find any mac app that can connect to it.
I suspect the camera is somehow transmitting the data via a RTP stream, but i wasn't able to connect to it.

I've tried other similar cameras, but they seem also to operate in the same unknown protocol.

Ideally, i'd like to find a solution to connect to it from something like VLC, and then use VLCKit on my iOS app to connect to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the stream from the camera to your app, there are other ways.

1. Each IP Camera should have been configured with RTSP URI by the manufacturer. Check in their website or in user manual. For example: **rtsp://192.168.0.5/video**.

If you couldn't find the URI, refer this link for "How can I find the right RTSP URI for my IP camera?": http://ipcamlive.com/faqs.
Related software download link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/

2. Using this RTSP URI, you can use any **RTSP player** example and get the camera feed to your app.